# Issue in submitting and updating the safari extension

Tags: safari-extension

I have my safari extension in the gallery.

Now I made few minor changes in my code and then resubmitted it for review (it takes a month to review, :( that is really a long time)

After almost a month, I received an email from safari , that my extension is rejected because of this Issue

**Please strip the extended attributes (`xattr -c path/to/extension.safariextension`) and rebuild your Safari Extension package using the latest version of Safari.**

I tried the above command but every time I face the same issue.

and also I am confused that if every time I update my code, I need to resubmit extension for review, then what is the use of this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/UpdatingExtensions/UpdatingExtensions.html

also, when I was going through all this, I got an email from safari that my certificate (which is used in extension builder to create .extz file) is going to expire in a month
I created a new certificate and created a new extz file.

but don't know that do I need to resubmit my extension or just update it on webserver.

so basically I have 3 issues/ confusions

1. Do I need to resubmit extension everytime I update code or just updating extz on web server will work
2. what do I have to do for this:
   "extension description within the Safari extension preference pane appears to be a placeholder"
3. Safari Extension certificate expires in a year, everyYear I need to resubmit extension or can update extz with new certificate on web server will work

Thanks in Advance

================update======================================

Submitting Extension removing extended attributes is actually resolved
by just running this command from MAC **xattr -c path/to/extension.safariextension**, and then rebuild and submit.

So, Question 2 is resolved , now I just want to clarify about other 2 parts of my question 1st and 3rd.

Comment: Can you tell me what you did about uploading your safari extension, where did you upload it? I keep getting the "Please strip extended attributes" message. I store the file in Dropbox, and then use that direct link. And I have done xattr -c <path> multiple times, but in the review I still get the same message..

Comment: @Anders when we remove xattr attributes and re generate the file .extz file for submit.. these attributes again get generated, so you again need to remove them.. from folder.. from extz file, and then upload this extz to some server, whose link you can provide while you submit the extension, that is how my issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with this placeholder -issue, fixed by adding/modifying proper Description in Information -section of Extension Builder.

Comment: Thanks @juvander , but I am not facing this issue now, I did few changes to the location of my .extension file to resolve it, but now I am getting another issue which says, 

Please strip the extended attributes (`xattr -c path/to/extension.safariextension`) and rebuild your Safari Extension package using the latest version of Safari.